# console.log doesn't escape % character correctly

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

With [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) it's possible to give a [`prinf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)-style format string followed by values to substitute into the output.

For example:

```js
console.log("The number is %d", 25);
```

Normally, the `%` can be escaped using another `%` when that isn't desired. So in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38885714/5743988) I posted an answer to explain that. However, I wasn't able to use a Stack Snippet to demonstrate.

```js
console.log('The number is %%d', 25);
// outputs as "%%d" instead of "%d"
```

Whatever code is handling `console.log` needs to remove one of the `%` symbols from the output so that it matches the output from a browser.

Comment: Can you link to a specification of `console.log` which supports your claim? The Wikipedia page that you linked to mentions neither JavaScript, nor `console.log`.

Comment: @NisseEngström The [node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) page mentions that it uses [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) in it's implementation, which documents `%%`, and I can't find documentation by any of the browsers, but I also haven't found a browser that doesn't have the behavior of removing one `%`.

Comment: And now the question that you answered appears to have been deleted…